# Using super class as the type parameter in generic subtype

Tags: java, generics

Why does this code piece give an incompatible type error?

```
public class Sample<T extends Number> {
    T doSomething() {
        return new Integer(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives a compiler error because to the compiler, `T` could be anything that extends `String`, so a `String` won't match `T` unless `T` is really `String`, which it can't and won't assume.  For this purpose, the compiler ignores the fact that `String` is a `final` class.

In this case, using a generic type parameter `T` is useless.  This is clearer and it will compile.

```
public class Sample {
    String doSomething() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand that... replace `String` with `Number` and return `new Integer(0)`; it still gives the same error. I know generics are exactly not useful in this example, it's just an over-simplified example of my problem.

Comment: Worth noting that using `new String` is degenerate.

Comment: @CihatKeser What if `T` is `Long` or `Double` or `BigInteger`?  You can't return an `Integer` here.  The return must be a `T` or `null`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I was so focused on the generics aspect that I wasn't even paying attention to that useless call to `new String` passing a `String`!  I have removed it now.

Comment: The answer is not related to the current question but i don't think is your fault @rgettman